# EF Core Reuse subquery in different queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a problem trying to reuse some subqueries. I have the following situation:

```
var rooms = dbContext.Rooms.Select(r => new
{
    RoomId = r.Id,
    Zones = r.Zones.Select(zr => zr.Zone),
    Name = r.Name,
    Levels = r.Levels.Select(lr => lr.Level),
    IdealSetpoint = (double?)r.Group.Setpoints.First(sp => sp.ClimaticZoneId == dbContext.ClimaticZonesLogs.OrderByDescending(cz => cz.Timestamp).First().ClimaticZoneId).Setpoint??int.MinValue,
    Devices = r.Devices.Select(rd => rd.Device)
}).ToList();

var tagsTypes = rooms.Select(r => r.Devices.Select(d => GetSetpointTagTypeId(d.DeviceTypeId))).ToList().SelectMany(x => x).Distinct().ToList();

predicate = predicate.And(pv => tagsTypes.Contains(pv.TagSettings.TagTypeId) &&
                                                         pv.ClimaticZoneId == dbContext.ClimaticZonesLogs.OrderByDescending(cz => cz.Timestamp).First().ClimaticZoneId);
var setpoints = valuesSubquery.Include(t=>t.TagSettings).Where(predicate).ToList();
```

This works fine, and generates the exact queries as wanted. The problem is that I want to have this subquery `dbContext.ClimaticZonesLogs.OrderByDescending(cz => cz.Timestamp).First().ClimaticZoneId` to be taken from a method and not repeat it every time I need it.

I've tested it with the database, where I have values in the corresponding tables, and I've tested the query with the database without any data in the corresponding tables. It works fine with no problems or exceptions.
But when I try to extract the repeating subquery in a separate method and execute it against empty database tables (no data) the `.First()` statement throws error. Here is the code:

```
protected long GetClimaticZoneId()
{
    return  dbContext.ClimaticZonesLogs.OrderByDescending(cz => cz.Timestamp).First().ClimaticZoneId;
}
```

and the query generation:

```
var rooms = dbContext.Rooms.Select(r => new
{
    RoomId = r.Id,
    Zones = r.Zones.Select(zr => zr.Zone),
    Name = r.Name,
    Levels = r.Levels.Select(lr => lr.Level),
    IdealSetpoint = (double?)r.Group.Setpoints.First(sp => sp.ClimaticZoneId == GetClimaticZoneId()).Setpoint??int.MinValue,
    Devices = r.Devices.Select(rd => rd.Device)
}).ToList();

var tagsTypes = rooms.Select(r => r.Devices.Select(d => GetSetpointTagTypeId(d.DeviceTypeId))).ToList().SelectMany(x => x).Distinct().ToList();

predicate = predicate.And(pv => tagsTypes.Contains(pv.TagSettings.TagTypeId) &&
                                                         pv.ClimaticZoneId == GetClimaticZoneId());

var setpoints = valuesSubquery.Include(t=>t.TagSettings).Where(predicate).ToList();
```

After execution I get `InvalidOperationException "Sequence do not contain any elements"` exception in the `GetClimaticZoneId` method:

I'm sure that I'm not doing something right.

Please help!

Regards,

Julian

Comment: Why do you want to run it as two queries though? It will now be running 2 queries against the database instead of (potentially) just one.

Comment: The first approach I've described the `var rooms = ...` query will run only one query. I do not want to run it as two queries, I want the `dbContext.ClimaticZonesLogs` query to be a subquery of the others

Comment: Yes, but it will run as another query if you do it this way.

Comment: That is the point of my question, what should I do to make that query reusable, and have it code on one place rather than  make copy/paste every time I need it

Comment: Of course this will throw an error - you are using `First()` and running it against an empty database. `First` per definition throws an Exception if there is no first element to take. if you do not want this to happen use `FirstOrDefault()` which will return null if there is no element.

And the first code snippet only works because in an empty database there is no `Room` to select so the statement containing `First` will never be called

Comment: @ Nannanas when I put the same piece of code inside like this: `sp.ClimaticZoneId == dbContext.ClimaticZonesLogs.OrderByDescending(cz => cz.Timestamp).First().ClimaticZoneId` does not throw an error, because it is translated like 'SELECT climatic_id FROM CLimaticZones ORDER BY Timestamp LIMIT 1', and it is sent as one query, but if I do it like the second scenario it is not as subquery, but a separate query that is invoked

Comment: Done, edited the original question

Comment: Run it as two queries. The part you want to reuse only gets an id value. That can't be expensive and using the same query multiple times inside a larger query only adds complexity to the query plan which may even make the whole operation perform worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Gert Arnold suggested, I used the `GetClimaticZoneId()` method to make a separate call to the database, get the `Id` and use it in the other queries. I gust modified the query to not generate exception when there is no data in the corresponding table:

```cs
protected long GetClimaticZoneId()
{
  return  dbContext.ClimaticZonesLogs.OrderByDescending(cz => cz.Timestamp).FirstOrDefault()?.ClimaticZoneId??0;
}
```